# What happened to Opera Dragonfly?

Tags: opera, opera-dragonfly

Using either 20.0.1387.82 or 22.0.1457.0 (developer)
When I right-click and select Inspect Element, I get a vanilla Developer Tools dialogue:

[image]

not the one always pictured:

[image]

It looks identical to Chrome's debugger (though I've uninstalled Chrome), most notably absent, the icons on top row and the remote debug facility.
Anyone know how I can get Dragonfly working on my machine?

Comment: Quentin is right, but you can also install the last Presto-based Opera, [12.16](http://www.opera.com/download/guide/?ver=12.16). That's what I use, actually, because I'm terribly conservative. Sure, it's starting to show its age, but I kind of prefer it to the newer Operas.

Comment: As @SáT says, the "old" and "new" Opera can happily co-exist. I use both for development as well. The old one gives me Dragonfly, which I prefer over other inspectors, as well as all my beloved customisation options, and the new one gives me the Blink rendering engine, basically Chrome with some added features. Looking forward to the day _all_ the features of the "old" one are in the "new" version... but there were so many, it'll probably take quite some time.

Comment: I have unfortunately come here looking for the same answer (I need to remote debug an OperaTV app on a TV with a presto based version of Opera and badly need this.  Got all excited to see the 12.16 download link, only to find it's been re-written to point to the new version, so no old versions to download anymore either.  BOOOOOO Opera, you used to be so good.  Guess it's back to Firefox for me and home made remote debug solutions. :-(

Comment: 15 mins later and a great big YAY!!!! - For anyone who wants it, file hippo still have V12.16 available for download : https://filehippo.com/download_opera/15472/

Answer (score 4):

Opera ditched their Presto rendering engine and built a new browser (also called Opera) around Blink (Google's fork of Webkit). It doesn't support Dragonfly any more.

There [are plans](http://news.softpedia.com/news/Here-Are-the-Things-Opera-Has-Confirmed-Is-Coming-Back-356920.shtml) to port it to the new browser.

Comment: -1 the answer is wrong. Opera is now only interested in removing features to simplify development and attract more users. Each version is a downgrade in terms of functionalities. They won’t port opera dragonfly, the same way they won‘t offer alternatives to opera links for syncing search engines *(and many other things)*. Each newer versions extend the ***“no longer can”*** list.